# Running application as user: MSComm32.ocx error

Tags: windows-server-2008, dependencies, vb6, dll

(I'm not sure this is the best place to ask this question, so if not, please redirect me to it)

I'm setting up a new win2008R2 terminal server and am having issues with an application that runs fine on our 2003 TS. If I run the application as a regular user I get the following error:

> Component 'MSComm32.ocx' or one of its dependencies is not correctly registered: a file is missing of invalid.

If I run the application as administrator, it runs fine.

I tried downloading MSComm32.ocx and registering it with regsvr32 (as admin) but without any luck.

How do I know what the dependencies are?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: I downloaded it and put it in the c:\windows\system32 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unregistering the ocx file, move it to the syswow64 folder and then register it. Strange as it might seem, that oddly named folder is where 32 bit libraries go on a 64 bit Windows machine.